# Why won't MEF Lazy load work in the ViewModel?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mef, lazy-loading

I'm trying to get Lazy to work for a collection in my ViewModel that I'm binding to.  The collection loads through MEF fine, but never gets displayed in the bound UI.

Here's the UI:

```
<Window x:Class="TestWindow"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

     <StackPanel>
          <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}">
               <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                         <Label Content="{Binding ItemTitle}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
               </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
          </ItemsControl>
     <StackPanel>
</Window>
```

The code-behind class:

```
public partial class TestWindow : Window
{
     public TestWindow()
     {
          InitializeComponent();
          this.DataContext = new TestVM();
     }
}
```

The ViewModel:

```
public class TestVM : INotifyPropertyChanged, IPartImportsSatisfiedNotification
{
     public TestVM()
     {
          //I'm using a static class to initiate the import
          CompositionInitializer.SatisfyImports(this);
     }

     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

     [ImportMany(typeof(MyItemBase))]
     public Lazy<MyItemBase>[] MyList { get; set; }

     public void OnImportsSatisfied()
     {
          this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MyList"));
     }
}
```

The base class for the items, and some inherited test classes:

```
[InheritedExport]
public class MyItemBase
{
    public MyItemBase()
    {

    }

    public string ItemTitle{ get; set; }
}

public class MyItem1: MyItemBase
{
    public MyItem1()
    {
        this.ItemTitle = "Item 1";
    }
}

public class MyItem2: MyItemBase
{
    public MyItem2()
    {
        this.ItemTitle = "Item 2";
    }
}
```

This works IF I just remove the Lazy loading.  However, I'll need to apply some export attributes later, which means going to Lazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that you want bind to a list of MyItembase object, but your actual binding is to a lazy arrray of MyItembase objects.(as long as you never call .Value for your lazy item nothing will happen)

i my projects i use a private lazy collection for mef and a normal ObservableCollection for wpf. btw i would prefer Constructor injection for your Mef import

```
public class TestVM : INotifyPropertyChanged, IPartImportsSatisfiedNotification
{
 public TestVM()
 {
      //I'm using a static class to initiate the import
      CompositionInitializer.SatisfyImports(this);

      this.MyList = new ObservableCollection();
      foreach(var lazyitem in _mefList)
      {
          this.MyList.Add(lazyitem.Value);
      }
 }

 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

 public ObservbableCollection<MyItemBase> MyList{ get; set; }

 [ImportMany(typeof(MyItemBase))]
 private IEnumarable<Lazy<MyItemBase>> _mefList { get; set; }

 public void OnImportsSatisfied()
 {
      //this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MyList"));
 }
```

}

Comment: Didn't know about the requirement to call .Value.  Doesn't putting the adding of items into the Constructor take away from the asynchronous load?  What about putting it in OnImportsSatisfied?  Even better would be if I could wrap it in an Rx Linq statement.

Comment: Marking as the answer because it correctly identified the problem, and provided the solution.  I may, however, go with an ExportFactory instead.